# Syntax for Application and configuration settings in Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

I added a variable to my release pipeline and now I want to use it in my application and configuration settings option in deploy azure app service. here is the sample syntax
 please note that the variable I defined is AzureAADClientSecret

```
-myAppSettings.AzureAADClientSecret $(AzureAADClientSecret)
```

The json I'm expecting in my appsettings.json is as follows

```
{
   "myAppSettings": {
    "AzureAADClientSecret": "",
}
```

this doesn't work. 
If I use `-AzureAADClientSecret $(AzureAADClientSecret)`, it adds it directly to the appsettings.json file. However I want it to be added specifically as a part of myAppSettings object inside the appsettings.json file and not directly to the appsettings.json.  Can you please share the right syntax for it?

Comment: Hi,Does my answer can help you achieve what you want? Feel free to share its latest status with us.

Answer (score 0):

For operating JSON file with powershell task. First you need to use `ConvertFrom-Json` to convert the JSON-formatting data.

So, try with changing your powershell into inline, and add follow script:

```
$JsonPath = "{the relative path of JSON file}" 
$CV = Get-Content $JsonPath | ConvertFrom-Json
$CV.myAppSettings.AzureAADClientSecret = "$(AzureAADClientSecret)"
$CV | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $JsonPath
```

**Note**: For `JsonPath` , add the relative path of your JSON file.